# SSH with ProxyCommand fails after update to Fedora 35

Tags: ssh, fedora

The command I use looks like:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='ncat --proxy-type socks5 --proxy 127.0.0.1:3744 %h %p' me@example.com
```

Since updating to Fedora 35, the connection fails with the error message

```
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

I confirmed that the proxy still works by using it with a web browser. The connection to the server still works using another computer or using Fedora 34 in a container. It fails when using Fedora 35 in a container. I can also reproduce the results with a different server.

Verbose output doesn't seem helpful

```
OpenSSH_8.7p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  FIPS 24 Aug 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/me/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/me/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ncat -v --proxy-type socks5 --proxy 127.0.0.1:3744 example.com 22
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.7
Ncat: Version 7.91 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to proxy 127.0.0.1:3744
Ncat: No authentication needed.
Ncat: Host example.com will be resolved by the proxy.
Ncat: connection succeeded.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.04 seconds.
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the same problem. Something seems broken with the nmap-ncat in fedora 35
(i.e nmap-ncat-7.91-8.fc35.x86_64)

As a work around you can use netcat-1.218-2.fc35.x86_64

or install directly `rpm -vhU https://nmap.org/dist/ncat-7.92-1.x86_64.rpm`

From https://nmap.org/download.html

Comment: FYI, I logged a bug for the issue

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2044364

Comment: This works, thanks. I wasn't sure how to determine where the issue occured